# How is “R v. Smith” pronounced?

Tags: legal-terms, common-law, legal-citation, naming-conventions

Is it “Are and smith”? “Rex/Regina and smith”? “The king/queen and smith”? What is the typical convention?

Comment: I would say "King vee Smith" but I don't consider my answer authoritative as I don't practice regularly in monarchies.

Comment: @ohwilleke Where does "King" come from? Is "R" a standard abbreviation in British citations (apparently from the Latin)? Is this question specific to the UK (if so, add the `united-kingdom` tag).

Comment: Wikipedia has, but without citation: "Criminal cases are pronounced with against. For example, R v Smith would be pronounced "the Crown against Smith".[3] The Latin words Rex, Regina, and versus are all rendered into English."  In particular this means that "the Crown" is also a possible rendering of "R".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_citation#Commonwealth_pronunciation

Comment: @Barmar The abbreviation R. is not limited to the United Kingdom. It applies in every country with a monarchy, constitutional or otherwise. For example, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand. I don't know if this appreciation is used in non-English speaking monarchies, but it would be a reasonable way to translate the local language into English.

Comment: I guess you had meant abbreviation not appreciation.

Answer (score 9):

It varies. See [Wikipedia: Case citation - Pronunciation of case titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_citation#Pronunciation_of_case_titles): "When case titles are read out loud, the *v* can be pronounced, depending on the context, as *and*, *against*, *versus*, or *vee*." And "[t]he Latin words *Rex*, *Regina*, ... are all rendered into English."<sup>1</sup>

You can see how various justices of the Supreme Court of Canada pronounce the **"v"** (ou le « c » en français) and the **"R."** when they call the case. Note that even individual justices are not consistent on the pronunciation of the "v."

- At the [hearing](https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=39401&id=2021/2021-04-22--39401&date=2021-04-22) for *R. v. Smith*, [2021 SCC 16](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/2021/2021scc16/2021scc16.html), Justice Moldaver pronounced the case as, "Her Majesty the Queen and Mark Anthony Smith."
- At the [hearing](https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=36059&id=2015/2015-03-20--36059&date=2015-03-20&fp=n&audio=n) for *R. v. Smith*, [2015 SCC 34](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/2015/2015scc34/2015scc34.html), Chief Justice McLachlin pronounced the case as, "Her Majesty the Queen versus Owen Edward Smith."
- At the [hearing](https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=40147&id=2023/2023-01-10--40147&date=2023-01-10) for *R. v. S.S.*, [2023 SCC 1](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/2023/2023scc1/2023scc1.html), Chief Justice Wagner pronounced the case as, "His Majesty the King versus S S."
- At the [hearing](https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=39416&id=2021/2021-11-02--39416&date=2021-11-02) for *R. v. Stairs*, [2022 SCC 11](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/2022/2022scc11/2022scc11.html), Chief Justice Wagner pronounced the case as, "Matthew Stairs against Her Majesty the Queen."
- For a more complex scenario, with more than two parties on a side, see the [hearing](https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=39182&id=2021/2021-03-24--39182&date=2021-03-24) of [*Grant Thornton LLP v. New Brunswick*, 2021 SCC 31](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/2021/2021scc31/2021scc31.html). Justice Moldaver refers to the "matter of Grant Thornton LLP et al. [pronounced "ett all"] versus the province of New Brunswick and between Grant Thorton International Limited versus the province of New Brunswick."
- At the [hearing](https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=36919&id=2017/2017-03-29--36919&date=2017-03-29&fp=n&audio=n) for  *Desjardins Sécurité financière, compagnie d’assurance vie c. Émond*, [2017 CSC 19](https://www.canlii.org/fr/ca/csc/doc/2017/2017csc19/2017csc19.html), Justice Abella pronounced the case as, "Desjardins Sécurité financière, compagnie d’assurance vie contre Mariette Émond et autres."

While delivering argument, counsel often just shorten the names of well-known cases. E.g. in the hearing for *R. v. Stairs*, one counsel referred to "R. v. Godoy" simply as "Godoy" (08:40):

> we accept, as this Court found in ***Godoy*** and in other cases ...

Another counsel later said (1:01:48):

> I'm referring in particular to a decision of the Manitoba Court of Appeal — ***R [pronounced "arr"] versus R M J T*** — it's reported at 2014 Manitoba — MBCA 36.

---

<sup>1. This answer was largely drafted to address an [earlier version of the question](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/97053/1) which emphasized the pronunciation of the "v", leading with the alternatives: "Is it 'Are vee smith'? 'Are and smith'?" However, this answer *also* addresses how the "R." is pronounced, so I will leave it mostly as-is.</sup>

Comment: The OP has clarified in a comment on the other answer that they are mainly wondering how the "R" is pronounced, not "v".

Comment: @phoog In my experience, the "et al." is rarely spoken aloud, and is pronounced "et" with a short e, and "al" like the proper name "Al".

Comment: "While delivering argument, counsel often just shorten the names of well-known cases. E.g. in the hearing for R. v. Stairs, one counsel referred to "R. v. Godoy" simply as "Godoy" (08:40):" The shortened form is not particular to criminal cases. It is used in almost all cases where one of the litigants is a common repeat litigant likely to be in many case names.

Comment: @Jen in my opinion your answer is still no less applicable to the question as it does still apply to the titular formulation which was not changed. In fact I think Your answer addresses both variables, and I apologise for drafting it (just slightly) too broadly. In fact the edit was mainly aimed at @DaleM’s answer, which only addressed one of the words’ pronunciations (which I think may have already been addressed in a previous answer on the site before) (and which was not in question to my mind because in any event I already knew most of what you included in your answer to cover it).

Comment: @ohwilleke not only that but even when both litigants are not likely/repeat litigants, I’ve often heard/seen the cases referred to simply by the name of the first party of the citation (typically the claimant), especially in contexts where the case has a landmark significance, is well known, frequently-cited, or is otherwise likely to be clear from just the abbreviated mention.

Comment: However in criminal law contexts where the prosecuting party is almost invariably “R.”, it’s obviously almost always referenced by the name of the defendant (or, I think… perhaps appellant, in case it’s something like a judicial review or maybe a criminal appeal, although don’t anyone quote me on this parenthesis).

Comment: Anyway, all in all, I’d call this a great answer. I would probably just add to it that (as I’ve read somewhere else or other) in the U.K., v. Is most often pronounced “and” while the “vee,” “versus,” and “against” variations have found greater use in the U.S. (as well, seemingly, as elsewhere). Don’t want to disturb your answer if the direct edit isn’t welcome though so will leave it up to you.

Answer (score 7):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

## The Crown against Smith

**v is “and” in civil trials and “against” in criminal ones**

However, language changes and “v”, “versus”, and “against” are all variously acceptable depending on the age and cantankerousness of the judge.

**R is “the Crown”**

Again, depending on the formality, “ar” may be acceptable.

Note that “R” is only used in first instance trials, “the King” or “the Queen” are used in appeals and those are pronounced as you’d expect.

Comment: Again I am led to wonder how this works when there are multiple parties on one or both sides of a case.  How does one distinguish the "and" that means "against" from the ones that mean "together with"?

Comment: Sorry, it was totally ambiguous from the question’s framing but this was actually mainly/more about the “R” than the “v”.

Comment: @phoog that’s actually a good point, and would probably make for a good question if you want to post it.

Comment: Why would that difference (between first instance trials and appeals) be,

Answer (score 1):

In the US, you will usually hear this as "vee," even though "versus" is correct. Others have said this, but the reason I wanted to write my own answer is because it is very, very common to hear people say "verse" which is definitely incorrect, but so common that it's usually just accepted. Nobody would bat an eye at "Are Verse Smith," for example.